# TFS Check which files have been manually merged

Tags: tfs

A merge has been completed in a local workspace. I'm interested to see which files were manually merged (ie which ones initially came up in the resolve conflicts window).

Is there any way to find this out now that all conflicts have been resolved?

Comment: What information are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shelve the merge and undo local changes. Then merge again and record the list of conflicts that cannot be automatically resolved.

This is the slow and painful answer. I sincerely hope there is a better way so I can delete this and not have to sit through a tonne of progress bars.

Comment: This is the only answer.